# Создание пошаговой игры

Tags: разработка-игр

Посмотрел как сейчас на коленке люди клепают инди игры под андроид\иос e.t.c. Созрел вопрос - куда двинуть, что использовать чтобы написать игру. Хотелось бы подобие Героев 3 на пк. Игру планирую под виндоус. И вообще кто сталкивался - наслько это утомительно? Хочу в качестве хоби накидать что нить аусорсное, может потом и комьюнити подтянется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала надо определится что вы хотите - движок или игру?

Игра - это по большей части контент + игровая механика. 
Движок - это инструмент для удобного создания механики.

Если вы хотите сделать опенсорсный движок, то тут ограничений нет. Пишите хоть на си, хоть на джава с оглядкой на производительность. Если же хотите делать игру, то лучше взять уже готовые движки типа Unity, Unreal engine, cocos2d и тд.

[Список движков.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> И вообще кто сталкивался - наслько это утомительно?

Утомительно или нет зависит от человека. Можно начать писать движок, замахаться и решить что это не твоё, а можно вникнуть и не оторвешь(если конечно много времени есть свободного).

В итоге решайте что именно вы хотите сделать, осваивайте инструменты и вперед. А дальше уже как пойдет. Большие компании пишут свои движки чтобы быть независимыми, инди(в большинстве) делают продукты на готовых движках, это экономит время и силы.

Comment: про OGRE и иже с ними немного видел информации. Да конечно свой движок писать не буду. А какой максимально простой в освоении. Возможно не самый функциональный

Comment: OGRE вроде как только графический движок. Я считаю что самый простой в освоении Unity, т.к. много документации и большое коммьюнити. В ассэт сторе куча контента и в инете куча туторов и примеров. 

http://unity3d.com/showcase/gallery - игры сделанные на юнити.

Comment: http://g2g.amplitude-studios.com/Games/Endless-Legend
во милота какая варгейм по типу героев как по скринам. интересно сколько трудодней на это потратили. а unity разве беспалтный?

Comment: @anunak freeware. В про версии доступна оптимизация, расширенное освещение, запекание и всякие такие плюшки. На ту игру потратили много усилий думаю. Попробуйте модель для начала слепить в каком-нибудь 3д редакторе и нарисовать текстуру. Думаю после этого поймете весь объем работ художников :)

Comment: отпуск начнется нужно будет попробовать что нибудь простое 
по сути мне и такой графики за глаза http://www.tortugateam.com/en/